# How can I get a checklist to penetration testing of PS networks?

Tags: penetration-testing

I need a check list for penetration testing PS (packet switched) network in 3g or 4g

## penetration_testing

Answer (score 0):

There will be wireless and wired testings are needed. I assumed you're talking about air trafficking. if it is 3g/4g it all radio spectrums which come under wireless testing activities. So you have to create the checklist based on the protocols which they are using.

For the general reference the given below URL might be helpful to you.
http://tec.gov.in/pdf/Studypaper/white%20paper%20on%20security%20testing.pdf